# How to catch ngToast with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, ngtoast

I need somehow to catch ngToast message after some action. I tried different solutions from this site, but they didn't help me and I don't know why. Does anyone has a working solution ? My last attempt was like:

```
var HomePage = require('./home.pageObject');

describe('Home Page tests', function () {
  var homePage = new HomePage();
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

  beforeEach(function () {
      browser.get('/#/');
  });

  it('should fail login', function () {
      var toast = $('.ng-toast');
      homePage.signinBtn.click();
      homePage.login('admin', 'Password')
          .then(function () {
              var toast = $('.alert');
              browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(toast), 3000);
          });
  });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the toast element once it is shown and then try to grab the message using css.

In one of our projects where we use angular-toastr, this does the trick:

```
element(by.css('#toast-container .toast-message')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function and call it in the test: 
First I'm waiting presence in the dom, then visibility and then I return the text:

```
this.returnToastText= function(){

    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.css(".alert"))), 3000).then(function () {
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css(".alert"))), 3000).then(function () {
            return toastText= element(by.css(".alert")).getText();
        })
    })

};
```

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track. I was trying to close the toast. Now I am using:
`browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); //Dont wait for toast timeout
var closeToast = $(".close");
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(closeToast))
            .then(() => {
                console.log(`Toast is present`)
                return true;
            })
closeToast.click();
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);`